# Server 2012 R2 System Disk Full (Unknown File)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, disk-space-utilization

The other day the system disk filled up due to IIS log files.

There were massive log files associated with the default web site.

I cleared these logs and disabled logging, the disk had plenty of free space at this point.

Now the disk is totally full again, I've checked WinDirStat and it reports 194gb of  in the root of the system disk.

I can't see the file(s) in explorer or winhex. I've run chkdsk.

How can I recover this disk space?

Comment: What did windirstat show? It lists files too. Is it your page file or a hibernation file or something? How much memory does his server have?

Comment: pagefile maybe ?

Comment: Try treesize free, it's much clearer than windirstat imho.

Comment: pagefile is 9.5gb, server has 64gb ram, windirstat lists the 194gb as "unknown"

Comment: also its eaten up the remaining space I cleared, so I can't really download anything atm.. any free space gets eaten up by this invisible unknown file

Comment: It could be (and probably is) the WinSxS folder.

Comment: Thanks joeqwerty, but I did check that and the sxs folder only seems to be ~270mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK turns out after I turned off IIS logging I started getting logs in System32/LogFiles/HTTPERR

These weren't shown in WindDirStat due to permissions, I think treesize free was a good idea from Martin, I just didn't have disk space to install it!